# Is it impossible for determinants of these matrices to both be negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, determinants, schur-complement

Suppose $A,B \in M_{n}(\Bbb{R})$ such that $A = \left[C_{1}\middle|\frac{I}{0\dots0}\right], B= \left[C_{2}\middle|\frac{I}{0\dots0}\right]$ , where $A$ and $B$ have different first columns (represented as $C_{1}, C_{2}$).

Thus we have $B = A+ \xi e_{1}^T$, where $\xi$ is a $n \times 1$ column vector and $e_{1}^{T} = [1, 0,\ldots,0]$

$\textbf{Assumptions}:$

Let $\lambda_{i}, i=1, \ldots, n$ denote the eigenvalues  of $AB^2$. Suppose we have the condition that $|\lambda_{i}|<1 \, \forall i$.

Let $\beta_{i}, i=1, \ldots, n$ denote the eigenvalues  of $A^2B$. Suppose we have the condition that $|\beta_{i}|<1 \, \forall i$.

$\textbf{Claim}:$

Then I have an intuition that $\textbf{ $\det(AB+A+I) < 0$ and $\det(BA+B+I)<0$ is not possible.}$
That is both of the determinants cannot be negative. I am not sure how to prove it?

$\textit{Some thoughts:}$

$(a) \textbf{Using $A = B+ \xi e_{1}^T$, we have }$
\begin{align}
AB+A+I &= A^2 + A + I + A \xi e_{1}^{T},\\
BA+B+I &= A^2 + A + I + \xi e_{1}^{T}(I+A)
\end{align}

Since the absolute values of the eigenvalues of $AB^2,$ and $A^2B$ are less than one, that means we have $|\det(AB^2)| < 1$ and $|\det(A^2B)|<1$.

\begin{align}
A^2B &= A^3 + A^2 \xi e_{1}^{T},\\
AB^2 &= A^3 + (\xi e_{1}^{T})^2 + 2A^{2} \xi e_{1}^{T}
\end{align}

$\textbf{(b)}$ If we proceed via the method of contradiction. if $\det(AB+A+I)<0$ and $\det(BA+B+I)<0$, then some of the eigenvalues of $AB^2$ or $A^2B$ will be greater than one in absolute value. THis would then violate the assumption of $|\lambda_{i}|<1 \forall i$,, $|\sigma_{i}|<1, \forall i$ .

$\textbf{(c)}$ Another thought is to use the perturbation argument: Fix $A, B$. Define $B(\epsilon):= A + \epsilon (B-A)$. For $\epsilon = 0$, we get $\det(A^2+A+I) \geq 0$ and hence the statement holds. For $\epsilon=1$, we have $B(1) = B$. If the statement fails in this case then there should be a minimal $\epsilon$ for which the statement is false. There might be a contradiction for $\epsilon < 1$?

Comment: Cross-posted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4487196/42969. – See https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/2638/116247 for some guidelines about cross-posting (wait some days, provide links, ...)

Comment: Please give an explicit example for $A$ and $B$, I don't see why $|\lambda_i|,|\beta_i|<1$.

Comment: True, there is no reason that $|\lambda_{i}|<1, |\beta_{i}|<1$ for any matrix $A,B$. But this is the assumption we have. Sorry, I should have been more careful with my writing. I have edited my question. I hope it makes clear?

Comment: More discussion about this question is taking place [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61759060#61759060).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer, now with added material.

Assume that $n$ is a multiple of 3, the other two cases should be similar. I'll denote $C_1\mapsto a$ and $C_2\mapsto b$, such that for, e.g., $n=6$,
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
a_2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
a_3 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
a_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
a_5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
a_n & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix},\quad
A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/a_n \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -a_1/a_n \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -a_2/a_n \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -a_3/a_n \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -a_4/a_n \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -a_5/a_n
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Note that $\det A = (-1)^{n-1}a_n$. The inverse of $A$ is easily calculated, see \eqref{1}, such that the determinant of $AB+A+I$ (and also of the other case, exchange $a_i$ and $b_i$) can be expressed via a Schur complement of the matrix $A^{-1}(AB+A+I) = B+I+A^{-1}$:
We take the Schur complement w.r.t. the first and last row/column and get
$$\tag{2}\label{2}
\det(AB+A+I)=\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1-\alpha_3 & \beta_1-\beta_2\\
\alpha_2-\alpha_3 & \beta_1-\beta_3
\end{pmatrix}
=\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 &1& \beta_2\\
\alpha_2 &1& \beta_3\\
\alpha_3 &1& \beta_1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where in the last step we used basic determinant rules.
The $\alpha_j$ and $\beta_j$, with $j\in\{1,2,3\}$, are simply given by
$$\tag{3}\label{3}
\alpha_j = -\delta_{3,j} + \sum_{k=0}^{n/3-1} a_{3k+j},
\qquad
\beta_j = -\delta_{3,j} + \sum_{k=0}^{n/3-1} b_{3k+j},
$$
with Kronecker's $\delta$. I’ve renamed OPs $\beta\mapsto\nu$.

For the eigenvalue assumption $|\lambda_i|, |\nu_i| <1$ it should be sufficient to consider the characteristic polynomials
\begin{align}\tag{4a}\label{4a}
P_a(\lambda)&=\det(A^2 B - \lambda I),\\
P_b(\nu    )&=\det(A B^2 - \nu     I),\tag{4b}\label{4b}
\end{align}
which can be calculated in a similar fashion: now we use $A^{-1}(A^2 B - \lambda I) = A B - \lambda A^{-1}$ and build the Schur complement w.r.t. the first, second and last row/column.

If the eigenvalues fulfill $|\lambda_i|<1$, the (real) zeroes of $P_a(\lambda)$ are between $\lambda=\pm 1$. At this point, I am not sure how to handle the complex zeroes (but see edit below). However, as $P_a(\lambda) \sim (-\lambda)^n$ for large $|\lambda|$, it should fulfill $P(-1)>0$ and $(-1)^{n}P(1)>0$. Let's evaluate $P_a(1)$ as one example,
$$\tag{5}\label{5}
P_a(1)=\det(A^2B-I)=
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \alpha_3 & \beta_2\\
\alpha_2 & \alpha_1 & \beta_3\\
\alpha_3 & \alpha_2 & \beta_1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Note the similarity of \eqref{2} and \eqref{5}, and that \eqref{5} can be generalised to $P_a(\lambda)$ using polynomials $\alpha_j(\lambda),\beta_j(\lambda)$.
So, the problem for arbitrary $n$ can be reduced to a discussion of the sign of the determinants of related $3\times3$ matrices.

Disclaimer: there might be sign errors due to even/odd $n$ and row/column permutations, please check.

**Edit 12.08.22, 09:00 CEST:**

From now on, we only consider even $n$, such that $n\mod 6 \equiv 0$, to get rid of the $(-1)^n$ terms.

As noted in my comments, $P_a(1)>0$ and $P_a(-1)>0$ are necessary conditions for $|\lambda_i|<1$, because complex $\lambda_i$ appear in complex conjugate pairs $\lambda_{i'}=\lambda_i^*$, such that
$$\tag{6}\label{6}
|\lambda_i|<1 \Rightarrow (\lambda_i \pm 1)(\lambda_i^* \pm 1)>0,
$$
and all factors in
$$\tag{7}\label{7}
P_a(\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^{n/2} (\lambda_i - \lambda)(\lambda_{i'} - \lambda)
$$
are positive for $\lambda=\pm 1$. Here, we grouped the real eigenvalues in arbitrary pairs $(i,i')$.

As shown above, $P_{a,b}(1)$ have the simple representation \eqref{5}.
Hence, we consider the matrix
$$\tag{8}\label{8}
D(\alpha,\gamma,\beta)=\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 &\gamma_3& \beta_2\\
\alpha_2 &\gamma_1& \beta_3\\
\alpha_3 &\gamma_2& \beta_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with 3d vectors $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, and formulate a geometric version of the problem. Define $\delta=(1,1,1)^T$, then the OPs conjecture holds, if
$$\tag{9}\label{9}
D(\alpha,\alpha,\beta)>0 \land D(\alpha,\beta,\beta)>0
\Rightarrow
D(\alpha,\delta,\beta)>0 \lor D(\beta,\delta,\alpha)>0.
$$
Note (a) that the determinant in 3D is known as triple product,
$$\tag{10}\label{10}
\det(a,b,c) = a \cdot (b \times c) = b \cdot (c \times a) = c \cdot (a \times b),
$$ and (b) that the cyclic index permutations of in \eqref{2}, \eqref{5} and \eqref{8} are rotations by $120^\circ$ around $\delta$. I guess that the OP question can now be answered through a discussion of the (rotated) directions of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\delta$ in 3D.

Comment: I will try to understand your answer carefully by working out the steps you mentioned..but I can't see why both can't be negative simultaneously.

Comment: Maybe one can show that if both Eqs. (2) are negative, then one zero of $P$ must be outside the interval $[-1,1]$, which can be seen from the sign of $P(\pm1)$. Remember that $\{\alpha_i,\beta_i\}$ are independent real variables, and that $$P_a(\lambda)=\prod_{i=1}^n (\lambda_i-\lambda).$$ Note that I have just corrected typos in (2) and (5).

Comment: I again thought about $P_a(-1)$. I think one can show due to complex conjugate pairs, that $P_a(-1)>0$ if all $|\lambda_i|<1$, as the point $-1$ lies left of all eigenvalues. Same of course holds for $P_b(-1)$. Therefore, one has to show that  $P_{a,b}(-1)>0$ contradicts D_a < 0 and D_b < 0. This should be possible.

Comment: Will it always be the case that $P_{a}(-1) > 0$ if  all $|\lambda_{i}| <1$? is it because $P_{a}(\lambda) \approx (-\lambda)^n$ [but then this holds for large $|\lambda|$, is in our case $\lambda=-1$ be considered large]

Comment: @BAYMAX: See my updated answer.

Comment: Nice idea! I wonder if you proved in the answer: $$
D(\alpha,\alpha,\beta)>0 \land D(\alpha,\beta,\beta)>0
\Rightarrow
D(\alpha,\delta,\beta)>0 \lor D(\beta,\delta,\alpha)>0.
$$?? because then it is a way of saying that $D(\alpha,\delta,\beta)<0$ and $D(\beta,\delta,\alpha)<0$ is not possible.. Is it intuitive that the implication $D(\alpha,\alpha,\beta)>0 \land D(\alpha,\beta,\beta)>0
\Rightarrow
D(\alpha,\delta,\beta)>0 \lor D(\beta,\delta,\alpha)>0$ is true? as I just want to see if in the current case it is true? because then other cases would be similar and conjecture becomes true

Comment: As I wrote, the proof of (9) remains open and might be performed geometrically or algebraically. Maybe you can work it out.

Comment: I was trying to check $\alpha, \beta$ as mentioned in eqn (2), (3) using Mathematica but it seems somewhere its is wrong: here: https://imgur.com/ghuln8m, can you please advise?

Comment: Also should $$\alpha_i = -\delta_{3,i} + \sum_{k=0}^{n/3} a_{3k+i}$$ be actually $$\alpha_i = -\delta_{3,i} + \sum_{k=0}^{n/3} a_{3k+i (\rm{mod} \, n)} $$ ?

Comment: I‘ll send you a MMA file later. Note that $i=1,2,3$ only, I‘ll rename the index $i$ of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ to $j$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ok, I was worried because in equation (3), when k=n/3, inside the summation we would have a_n+j but we only have a_1,..., a_n in matrix A

Comment: True, a typo, it should read $n/3-1$.

Comment: Thanks, I am still thinking about how Schur complement of $B+I+A^{-1}$ still gives information about the determinant of $AB+A+I$? I am reading about Schur complements to understand this but seems like I can see that Schur complement of $D$ in $M$ is $A - BD^{-1}C$, where $M = \begin{bmatrix} A & B\\ C & D\end{bmatrix}$ more discussion here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138505/discussion-on-schur-complement

Answer (score 1):

OK, second try, equation references are pointing to my other answer:

Using the definitions (3) for $\alpha_j$ and $\beta_j$, we can proof the OPs conjecture in the following way: As the determinants
$$
\begin{align}
D_a = \det(AB+A+I) \tag{11a}\label{11a}\\
D_b = \det(BA+B+I) \tag{11b}\label{11b}
\end{align}
$$
are continuous functions of the $a_i$ and $b_i$ (and $\alpha_j$ and $\beta_j$), and both shall be negative, w.l.o.g. we can assume that, say, either $D_a=0$ crosses zero while the other is still positive, $D_b>0$, or, both are zero simultaneously. This case is handled first.

##### case $D_a=D_b=0$

First we show that $D_a$ and $D_b$ cannot simultaneously vanish under the OPs eigenvalue condition $|\lambda_i|<1$.

As can be seen from (2), w.l.o.g. the condition $D_a = D_b = 0$ is equivalent to $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3$.
(Note that this condition can be solved for, e.g., $a_1$ and $a_2$.)
Inserting this solution into (5), we immediately see that the first two columns of (5) become linearly dependent, such that the characteristic polynomial (4a) reads $P_a(1)=0$. Therefore, we have identified one eigenvalue $\lambda_1=1$, contradicting the assumption that all eigenvalues $|\lambda_i|<1$. The other possible case $\beta_1=\beta_2=\beta_3$ would give $P_b(1)=0$.

##### case $D_a=0 \land D_b>0$

Now we turn to the case $D_a=0 \land D_b>0$: Then, from (2) we see that
$$\tag{12}\label{12}
\alpha_1=\beta_2 \land \alpha_2=\beta_3 \land \alpha_3=\beta_1
$$
must hold. Inserting this into (2) for the determinant $D_b$, we get the inequality
$$
\begin{align}
D_b &= \det
\begin{pmatrix}
\beta_1 &1& \alpha_2\\
\beta_2 &1& \alpha_3\\
\beta_3 &1& \alpha_1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\det\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_3 &1& \alpha_2\\
\alpha_1 &1& \alpha_3\\
\alpha_2 &1& \alpha_1
\end{pmatrix} \tag{13a}\label{13a} \\
\\
&= -\frac{(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)^2 + (\alpha_2-\alpha_3)^2 + (\alpha_3-\alpha_1)^2}{2} < 0 \tag{13b}\label{13b}
\end{align}
$$
which contradicts the assumption. Therefore, the only continuous path to negative $D_a$ and $D_b$ goes through $D_a=D_b=0$, at which point $\lambda_1=1$.

Comment: I am thinking as why there cannot be a continuous path from $D_{a} = 0 $ and $D_{b}<0$ to $D_{a}<0$ and $D_{b}<0$ ?

Comment: Start with a valid solution where $|\lambda_i|<1$, $|\nu_i|<1$ and $D_a>0$, $D_b>0$, for example $a_i=b_i=0$, where $\lambda_i=\nu_i=0$ and $D_a=D_b=1$. Then vary $a_i,b_i$ until $D_a=0$. I showed above that then also $D_b=0$ must hold. In this case one eigenvalue $\lambda_1=1$. Hence you cannot continuously reach the regime where $D_a<0 \land D_b<0$.

Comment: Ok, if $D_{a}=0$ then also $D_{b}=0$ must hold? because the case $D_{a}=0$ and $D_{b}<0$ is possible from eqn (13 b).. so if $D_{a}=0$ then $D_{b}<0$ must hold?

Comment: In the case of $D_{a}=0$ and $D_{b}<0$ one eigenvalue $\lambda_{1}=1$ too? how this excludes the case of continuity to reach $D_{a}<0$ and $D_{b}<0$ ?

Comment: what problem we face if there is no continuous path to reach the regime $D_{a}<0$ and $D_{b}<0$? what if we reach the regime $D_{a}<0$ and $D_{b}<0$ discontinuously? it might be a contradiction as determinants are continuous functions ... The moment we have $D_{a} = 0$, I think then atleast one eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ violating it to be less than one.. and moving ahead will only give eigenvalues $\geq 1$ into the regiem of $D_{a}<0$ and $D_{b}<0$..is this correct argument?

Comment: I don't think eqn (12) is true. If $D_{a} =0 $ AND $ D_b > 0$, then $\alpha_1 = m \beta_2 + n, \alpha_2 = m \beta_3 + n, \alpha_3 = m \beta_1 + n$ for some $m,n \in \Bbb{R}$. And that does not imply $D_b < 0$. And hence, eqn (13a, 13b) is false. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I think you are correct. I don't know how to resolve this issue.